# Ping from ASA over Site to Site VPN

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, ping, sslvpn

There are two things I'm trying to solve which are essentially the same problem.

1. Cannot ping from the ASA to remote devices over a site to site VPN terminated on the ASA.
2. ASA AnyConnect LDAP lookups for an LDAP server over a VPN also does not work.

I have the management-access command added so that the LDAP server can ping the inside interface over the VPN.

Here is relevant config

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 123.123.123.2 255.255.255.248
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.10.10.254 255.255.255.0
!
object network Branch2
 subnet 192.168.78.0 255.255.255.0
!
access-list outside_cryptomap_1 extended permit ip 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 object Branch2
!
nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_10.10.10.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_10.10.10.0_24 destination static Branch2 Branch2 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
!
crypto map outside_map 2 match address outside_cryptomap_1
crypto map outside_map 2 set peer 123.123.123.3
crypto map outside_map 2 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA
!
management-access inside
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the configurations. You can obfuscate passwords and public addresses, but we need to see the full configuration.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the full configuration. There are other configurations that may affect this. You need to give us everything, and please use the built-in markdown instead of trying to use HTML. There is the Preformatted-Text option (`{}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this and was actually really simple.
I was running **ping 192.168.78.100**.
I just needed to instead run **ping inside 192.168.78.100**.

Comment: You should accept you answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.